# Como estilizar a barra de rolagem geral do site?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Estava olhando na net uns templates e fiquei curioso com [esse aqui](http://themes.designorbital.com/?theme=Farad). 
A barra de rolagem dele não faz parte do browser pelo que vejo mas sim do DOM.

Como é isso?

Comment: Isso que você quer? http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: @Felipe Stoker, então a scrollbar n faz parte do browser?

Comment: Este site do corpo da pergunta está simulando uma scrollbar. A do meu browser aqui no SOpt não aparece no DOM, a desse site sim. No caso, o link do Felipe Stoker mostra uma **particularidade** de um determinado engine em colocar os elementos dentro do DOM de maneira "extraoficial", e nada garante que isso um dia será usado por qualquer outro browser, e se for, cada um pode fazer do seu jeito.

Comment: Inclusive testei o tal site aqui e fica horrível rolar a tela com a _scroll wheel_ do mouse pelo fato de os caras terem reimplementado a funcionalidade que devia ser da barra original.

Comment: @Bacco Pois é, esse tema é bom mas essa scroll bar é tensa.

Comment: @Bacco, é permitido postar perguntas sobre temas não tecnicos? Tipo uma reflexão sobre o mercado de T.I, coisa assim...

Comment: O meu conselho é, nunca altere algo que é do usuário(o usuário personaliza o navegador dele como ele gosta), ele pode não gostar da sua personalização forçada e achar um insulto, conheço vários que ficariam indignados, inclusive eu.

Answer (score 1):

No site em questão, foi utilizado o plugin [NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll) (jQuery).

Resumindo o funcionamento: ele coloca um `overflow: hidden` na tag `html` para sumir com as barras do navegador e cria uma "falsa" barra de rolagem; uma `div` que se comporta como uma barra. E depois ele faz o *scroll* manualmente, detectando os eventos `mousewheel` e fazendo a rolagem, provavelmente com jQuery, através de `scrollTop()`.

Apesar de ser mais bonito, isso diminui a performance além de que a rolagem fica estranha, às vezes, como aconteceu nesse caso.

Em navegadores *webkit* (Chrome e Safari) existem pseudo classes para estilizar a barra. Veja aqui: [Custom Scrollbars in WebKit](http://davidwalsh.name/custom-scrollbars)

Comment: Ressalte-se que, a menos que haja um bom motivo, aumentar o tempo de acomodação do conteúdo é uma PÉSSIMA ideia... Cansa o olho, irrita os usuários mais ágeis (pra não falar nos apressados...) e de uma forma geral é um esforço com grande chance de sair pela culatra.